# How to restart MySQL?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

I am running MySQL 5.1.54 and installed it on Ubuntu through the terminal using the command

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

I changed the `my.cnf` file and would like to stop and then start the database. I've tried the following

```
sudo /usr/bin/mysqld_safe stop
```

My question is how do I know that the database is stopped? When I run the above command, followed by

```
sudo mysql -uuser -ppassword
```

I can log right back into the database. Shouldn't it tell me that the database is not running?

**EDIT:**
I've also tried

```
mysqladmin -uuser -ppassword shutdown
```

and then

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

I get the following output

```
david    12093  0.0  0.0   6052  1276 pts/1    T    May10   0:00 nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
root     12267  0.0  0.0   6396  1436 pts/1    T    May10   0:00 sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
root     12269  0.0  0.0   6052  1388 pts/1    T    May10   0:00 nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
mysql    15371  0.3  0.1  55344  9088 ?        Ssl  10:53   0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
david    15512  0.0  0.0   5304   864 pts/1    R+   10:54   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

Does the above output mean that MySQL has been shut down? If I run `mysql -uuser -ppassword` I can still log into MySQL.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You should really use the Sys-V init scripts located in `/etc/init.d`.

**Start:**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

**Stop:**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

**Restart / reload configs:**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

**Check run status:**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql status
```

Comment: I tried that and I get the following error message `Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mysql status'

Comment: @David This is the only right answer. `service` is just a small program that looks up the right init.d script for you. Even though it throws you the "error message", `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start/stop` has still done its job. Using `service` is just the "new way" of using startup scripts. To use `service`, just execute this on the terminal: `service mysql stop` or start.

Comment: @BloodPhilia, I tried `service mysql stop` and I get the following message: `Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.72" (uid=1000 pid=17673 comm="stop mysql ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Stop" error name="(unset)" requested_reply=0 destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init"))`. Any ideas?

Comment: @David Did you try using it with sudo? Like `sudo service mysql stop`?

Comment: @BloodPhilia. You suggestion worked. Thank you for the clarifications.

Comment: Note that Redhat distros no longer have many of these scripts.

Comment: when I am trying with this command, it is failing - I am logged on as root. `sudo /usr/bin/mysql status
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Comment: Using `/etc/init.d/mysql` made all my `localhost` in php not working. They would need to be replaced by `127.0.0.1`. With `service mysql` there wasn't that issue. (Debian 8, Apache 2.4.10, MySQL 5.7.17, php 7.0)

Answer (score 16):

In Ubuntu machines, you can restart the mysql using both commands :

```
 1. sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart

 2. # service mysql restart
```

Comment: On Debian as well. But the first command made all my `localhost`s not working. They would need to be replaced by `127.0.0.1`. The latter one didn't have that issue.

Answer (score 5):

To shutdown mysql, run:

```
mysqladmin -uuser -ppassword shutdown
```

where user and password is that for a user with the proper [SHUTDOWN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_shutdown) privilege

To check that it has been shut down:

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

If any processes (other than the 'grep' command) show up, it hasn't been shutdown.

Comment: I followed your instructions and I get an output. I've edited my question using your procedure. I can tell me if I'm on the right track?

Comment: I think shutdown stops and then automatically starts mysql. Is there a command to permanately stop mysql?

Comment: @David the automatic restarting is not a behaviour of mysqladmin shutdown . probably ubuntu's /etc/init.d/mysql behaviour? I'm not sure. I think @gerryk's answer is the correct one for your operating system.

Comment: This is the right answer for shutting down the database. However, I had to perform an additional step `sudo service mysql stop` to make service inactive. `ps aux | grep mysql` and `sudo service mysql status` are helpful commands too

Answer (score 2):

the systemctl utility available by default in used to manage services in your linux box. it can be used to start, restart and stop services. There are other options you can use. checkout systemctl ?

```
systemctl stop mysql
systemctl start mysql
```

Comment: Please add some detail about why this should help. Non-explanatory answers are discouraged, which likely led to the downvote.

Comment: This is helpful if you get command not found "/etc/init.d/mysql" and on "service mysql restart". My site was down and didn't have time to debug why those other answers didn't work so I tried this and it worked thanks! (on debian)

Comment: Helpful, my server was full and mysql was in a broken state. Stopping and restarting fixed the problem (note that startup took some time, probably because of journaling).

Answer (score 1):

You can use kill -9 "PID" command to do that, the MySQL Process ID (PID) you can get running ps -a or top commands. Then you can start it again by calling ./"main process".

Comment: Hi I'm new to the command line and MySQL. Can you show me exactly what I need to type into the terminal?

Comment: kill -9 is a little rude, as it doesn't let a process clean up after itself.

Comment: I don't recommend doing this. Depending on what MySQL is doing at the time when it suddenly stops, you might restart to some unhappy databases.

Answer (score 1):

use the following command to restart mysql

```
    # mysql start/stop/restart
    # MAC
    $ cd /path/mysql/bin
    $ mysql.server restart

    #Linux
    $ /etc/init.d/mysqld restart

    or

    $ service mysqld restart

    or

    $ systemctl restart mysqld
```